# Rails Undefined Method include when including a module in `lib` dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, helper

I cannot load my `PactHelper` module from my `lib` dir.

```
# lib/pact_helper.rb

module PactHelper
    def so_something

    end
end
```

and

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController

    include PactHelper

    def new
        ...
    end
end
```

returns `undefined method 'include' for #<RegistrationsController:0x5287cf8>`

Could someone explain to me why my module is not being included?

Comment: if you want to use helpers inside the rails app, put them in the app/helpers and they get included automatically. If you want to put them in the lib dir, you have to add the lib dir to the autoload path inside the application.rb ``config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
require 'pact_helper.rb'
```

Above:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
```

In:

registrations_controller.rb